# capturing screenshot from different uiview of tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller, screenshot

Im trying to capture the screen from a tabbaritem using actionsheets.
the actionsheet is called when i press on the tabbaritem2.
I want to capture the screen of the viewcontroller from the tabbaritem1.
and tried using this code.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

I can see tabbaritem1 on the screen but it always captures the screen of tabbaritem2...
Can this problem be solved?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to save the current view and not the ViewController contained in your TabBarController's ViewController hierarchy. Do something more like this (change according to where your ViewController lies in your hierarchy.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
YourOtherViewController *yourOtherViewController = (YourOtherViewController*)[self.tabBarController objectAtIndex:0]; // This index needs to be changed for your specific controller you wish to screenshot
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourOtherViewController.view.frame.size);
[yourOtherViewController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```